# Ubuntu Refuses to Change Backlight Brightness

Tags: brightness, backlight

I've attempted to change the Backlight Brightness, by both the keyboard setting and directly in the screen settings. Both show that I've changed the brightness down to minimum neither actually changed the brightness level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set the backlightbrightness to changable in xorg.conf?

You need administrative properties for that, so open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/x11/xorg.conf
```

then please put this

```
Option          "RegistryDwords"        "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
```

As shown here

```
Section "Device"
..
..
..
Option          "RegistryDwords"         "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

If the file does not exist, you can create it.

Comment: Thank you that fixed the problem very nicely. I'm wondering atm, why it wasn't enabled by default. If you had any information on that, that could be interesting to know. Again, thanks I've had this problem for awhile.

Comment: If xorg.conf doesn't exist, it should be created?

Answer (score 0):

clone the following repo, paste the `backlight.sh` script to `/bin` and make it executable. after this run the following command in a root terminal.

`sudo backlight.sh "brightness-level"` ## replace the "brightness-level" with a number.

to clone the repo:

`git clone https://github.com/el-beth/backlight.sh.git`

read the README for more.